# Mysql count number of rows which have same value

Tags: mysql

I have in my table 3 rows. 2 of them with the same value (valueA) on field status and the 3-rd one with another value (valueB).

What i want to do is to display a message to show me how many rows with the same value exists. Example below:

EX: There are 2 status value in the database
    There are 1 status value in the database

How can i achive that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need  group by and count

```
 select your_column_name, count(*) from your_table 
 group by your_column_name;
```

in your case assuming `status` is th column name

```
select concat("there is " , count(*), "  status in your db") from your_table
group by status;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `group by`, you can learn more about `GROUP BY` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

In your case query would look something like:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as `total`
FROM <table>
GROUP BY `status `
```